# Matlab R2010b setting up MySql 

Tags: mysql, matlab

I'm trying to setting up a mySql connection using Matlab, I have read I few tutorial but unfortunately I can't get work of them. I had tried to compile the source(.cpp) but I got the following error:

```
Error: Could not detect a compiler on local system 
which can compile the specified input file(s) 

  C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2010B\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: No compiler options file could be found to compile source code. Please run "mex -setup" to rectify.
```

So I I typed "mex -setup"

```
Please choose your compiler for building external interface (MEX) files: 

Would you like mex to locate installed compilers [y]/n? y

Select a compiler: 

[0] None 

Compiler:
```

but there is no compiler.

Anybody can help me, how can I make a connection between matlab and mysql, I'm using windows 7 64 bit and Matlab 2010b.

I already installed wampserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to establish MySQL connection from MATLAB using JBCC connector?

I did it successfully and put the complete workflow with the code example (requires Database Toolbox) in this question:

[connection of MATLAB 7.0 and MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960320/connection-of-matlab-7-0-and-mysql)

Haven't try on 64-bit though. Please let me know if it will fail.

---

**UPDATE**

You can also try the following submissions to File Exchange that do not require the Database toolbox:

- [queryMySQL](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28237)
- [Access a MySQL database](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17897-access-a-mysql-database)

Comment: Whit these I get the following error:??? Undefined function or method 'database' for input arguments of type 'char'.

Error in ==> connectTest at 12
conn = database(dbName, user , password, jdbcDriver, jdbcString);
 
??? Undefined function or method 'database' for input arguments of type 'char'.

Comment: @iUngi: Sorry, it requires Database Toolbox available from the Mathworks. I'll update the answer. Probably there is another way using just java, I'll have a look.

Comment: Finally I found the answer at the morning but this solution is the same that you wrote in the Update. So if somebody is still looking for a connection between Matlab and MySQL here is the solution: Download the zip from the :http://sourceforge.net/projects/mym/ and compile using mex. If somebody has problem with compilation under windows 64bit I can help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you installed Matlab 64-bit as well, which does NOT come with a built-in MEX compiler (32-bit version uses lcc). You have a few options, but the easiest is to install Visual C++ Express (it's free! http://www.microsoft.com/express/Windows/) which will give you a 64-bit compatible compiler in the mex -setup listing. You'll have to double check which versions of the compiler 2010b is compatible with though.

Caveat: I tried this once and couldn't get it to work, but it was with like 2007b or something, and I didn't try that hard, I just installed 32-bit Matlab.